# My convolutional network loss does not change and keeps stagnant throughout the training. how do fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, relu

I am trying to train a convolutional network but the loss does change no matter what i do.  I want to know where i am going wrong and also would appreciate any friendly advises as this is my first time i am dealing with such large data.

I have tried many combinations of optimizers(adam,SGD,adamdelta...),loss functions(sqauare mean error,binary cross entropy....) and activation(Relu,elu,selu....) but the problem still persists.

Nature of my project: this is my attempt at training a simple self driving car in simulation.

Training data: the training data is split in around ~4000 .h5 files. Each file has exactly 200 images with respective data for each image like speed,acceleration etc.

Due to the nature of the data I decided to train in mini batches of 200 and cycle through all the files.

```
# model (I am a beginner so forgive my sloppy code)
rgb_in = Input(batch_shape=(200, 88, 200, 3), name='rgb_in')
conv_1 = Conv2D(filters=10,kernel_size=5,activation="elu",data_format="channels_last",init = "he_normal")(rgb_in)
conv_2 = Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=5,activation="elu",data_format="channels_last",init = "he_normal")(conv_1)
conv_3 = Conv2D(filters=24,kernel_size=5,activation="elu",data_format="channels_last",init = "he_normal")(conv_2)
conv_4 = Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,activation="elu",data_format="channels_last",init = "he_normal")(conv_3)
conv_5 = Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,activation="elu",data_format="channels_last",init = "he_normal")(conv_4)
flat = Flatten(data_format="channels_last")(conv_5)
t_in = Input(batch_shape=(200,14), name='t_in')
x = concatenate([flat, t_in])
dense_1 = Dense(100,activation="elu",init = "he_normal")(x)
dense_2 = Dense(50,activation="elu",init = "he_normal")(dense_1)
dense_3 = Dense(25,activation="elu",init = "he_normal")(dense_2)
out = Dense(5,activation="elu",init = "he_normal")(dense_3)
model = Model(inputs=[rgb_in, t_in], outputs=[out])
model.compile(optimizer='Adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')



for i in range(3663,6951):
    filename = 'data_0'+str(i)+'.h5'
    f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
    rgb = f["rgb"][:,:,:,:]
    targets = f["targets"][:,:]
    rgb = (rgb - rgb.mean())/rgb.std()
    input_target[:,0] = targets[:,10]
    input_target[:,1] = targets[:,11]
    input_target[:,2] = targets[:,12]
    input_target[:,3] = targets[:,13]
    input_target[:,4] = targets[:,16]
    input_target[:,5] = targets[:,17]
    input_target[:,6] = targets[:,18]
    input_target[:,7] = targets[:,21]
    input_target[:,8] = targets[:,22]
    input_target[:,9] = targets[:,23]
    a = one_hot(targets[:,24].astype(int),6)
    input_target[:,10] = a[:,2]
    input_target[:,11] = a[:,3]
    input_target[:,12] = a[:,4]
    input_target[:,13] = a[:,5]
    output[:,0] = targets[:,0]
    output[:,1] = targets[:,1]
    output[:,2] = targets[:,2]
    output[:,3] = targets[:,4]
    output[:,4] = targets[:,5]
    model.fit([rgb,input_target], output,epochs=10,batch_size=200)
```

The result:

```
Epoch 1/10
200/200 [==============================] - 7s 35ms/step - loss: 6.1657
Epoch 2/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3812
Epoch 3/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2955
Epoch 4/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2778
Epoch 5/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2778
Epoch 6/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2778
Epoch 7/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2778
Epoch 8/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2778
Epoch 9/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2778
Epoch 10/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 2.2778
Epoch 1/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
Epoch 2/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
Epoch 3/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
Epoch 4/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
Epoch 5/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
Epoch 6/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
Epoch 7/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
Epoch 8/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
Epoch 9/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
Epoch 10/10
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.9241
```

And lastly I will appretiate if you any advice for me regarding the project。

Comment: You may use MaxPooling2D layers. They help to reduce dimension but also preserve the potential features.

Comment: Have you normalized inputs to be in range `[0, 1]`? If not, this is the first thing to try.

Comment: I have normalized the input and also added MAxPooling2D layers but the it didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used cyclic learning rate and it has fixed the problem.
for who ever has suffered a similar issue, here is a link to it

https://github.com/bckenstler/CLR

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [ReduceLROnPlateau callback?](https://keras.io/callbacks/#reducelronplateau)

```
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', patience=6)

model.fit(X,y,num_epochs=666,callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```